# ошибка в pygame Python

Tags: python, pygame

```py
import pygame
import sys

def run():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(1200, 800)
    pygame.dysplay.set_caption("Космические защитники")
    bg_color = (0, 0, 0)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        pygame.display.flip()
run()
```

ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python code\my 1 game.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Какую именно ошибку - нужно указывать текст ошибки прямо в вопросе

Comment: А, ну тогда да - нужно установить собственно `pygame`, либо вы не из того окружения запускаете, куда установлен `pygame`

Answer (score 2):

Вроде не активировано

```
python -m pip install pygame
```